# pyspark UDF returns AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sort_values'

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm having a hard time with my program, I'm trying to apply a UDF to a dataframe and getting an error msg as per my title. Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

df = pd.DataFrame({
              'ID':[1,2,2],
              'dt':[pd.Timestamp.now(),pd.Timestamp.now(),
                  pd.Timestamp.now()]})
df.head()

def FlagUsers(df,ids,tm,gap):
  df=df.sort_values([ids,tm])
  df[ids]=df[ids].astype(str)
  df['timediff'] = df.groupby(ids)[tm].diff()
  df['prevtime']= df.groupby (ids)[tm].shift()
  df['prevuser']= df[ids].shift()
  df['prevuser'].fillna(0,inplace=True)
  df['timediff']=df.timediff/ pd.Timedelta('1 minute')
  df['timediff'].fillna(99,inplace=True)
  df['flagnew']=np.where((df.timediff<gap) & (df['prevuser']==df[ids]),'existing','new' )
  df.loc[df.flagnew == 'new','sessnum'] = df.groupby([ids,'flagnew']).cumcount()+1
  df['sessnum']=df['sessnum'].fillna(method='ffill')
  df['session_key']= df[ids].astype(str)+"_"+df['sessnum'].astype(str)
  df.drop(['prevtime', 'prevuser'], axis =1, inplace= True)
  arr=df['session_key'].values
  return arr

# Python Function works fine:
FlagUsers(df,'ID','dt',5)


s_df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
s_df.show()

spark.udf.register("FlagUsers", FlagUsers)
s_df = s_df.withColumn('session_key',FlagUsers(s_df,'ID','dt',5))
```

My function works fine in python but when i try to run it in Spark it does not work? i'm really sorry if this is a silly question! Thank you & Best Wishes

Comment: Within an udf, you cannot access the dataframe or execute grouping operations. And udf only operates on a single row. You should try to translate the udf into calls of the dataframe api

Comment: thank you for your reply. I'm a bit new to this, do you know any good source i could read about this particular problem?

Comment: You could have a look at the methods of the [dataframe](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.html), especially the groupBy function. A good approach would be a think about the problem more like a SQL task, not like a Pandas dataframe task.

Answer (score 0):

pyspark udf is not same as other native python udf, it has specific requirements,

Please experiment with pandas udf.

it is several times faster and better
https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-python-pandas.html